# How can I programmatically convert a string to number to remove the green warning triangle (Aspose Cells)?

Tags: excel, number-formatting, aspose, aspose-cells

I have two columns in my sheet wherein each cell has the green warning triangle with the message, "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostraphe."

I can manually clear these green warnings triangles in Excel by selecting "Convert to Number" from the context menu.

I want to do this programmatically, though, of course. How to do that?

Note in the screenshot below that the Qty column works fine (the data in it is an int; the two columns that cause the green warning icon are strings, but they "look like" ints to Excel, I guess, causing the problem):

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static readonly string NUMBER_FORMAT_ZERO = "0";
. . .
var flag = new StyleFlag
{
    CellShading = true,
    FontName = true,
    FontSize = true,
    FontColor = true,
    FontBold = true,
    NumberFormat = true
};

Cell qtyCell = customerWorksheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, QTY_COL];
qtyCell.PutValue(frbdbc.Qty);
var qcStyle = qtyCell.GetStyle();
qcStyle.Font.Name = fontForSheets;
qcStyle.IsTextWrapped = false;
qtyCell.SetStyle(qcStyle);

Cell CWeekCell = customerWorksheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, CWEEK_COL];
CWeekCell.PutValue(frbdbc.CWeek);
var cwStyle = CWeekCell.GetStyle();
cwStyle.Font.Name = fontForSheets;
cwStyle.IsTextWrapped = false;
cwStyle.Custom = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.NUMBER_FORMAT_ZERO;
CWeekCell.SetStyle(cwStyle, flag);

Cell PAItemCell = customerWorksheet.Cells[rowToPopulate,
    PAITEMCODE_COL];
PAItemCell.PutValue(frbdbc.PAItemCode);
var paiStyle = PAItemCell.GetStyle();
paiStyle.Font.Name = fontForSheets;
paiStyle.IsTextWrapped = false;
//paiStyle.Custom = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.NUMBER_FORMAT_ZERO;
PAItemCell.SetStyle(paiStyle); //, flag);
```

As you can see, I'm trying both with and without adding the custom number format and the flag to the style, yet they both turn out the same: with the green warning messages.

What do I need to do to fix this? For these two columns I supposed I could do this:

```
CWeekCell.PutValue(Convert.ToInt32(frbdbc.CWeek));
```

...but there are a couple of other columns whose values *sometimes* look to Excel like ints, but sometimes don't, containing values such as "6679    667904" and "2134LB"

So to pull that same trick with them would really get convoluted, checking to see if they *could* be converted to ints, and then only doing so if they can. There's got to be a better way to just treat all values as text. ... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your underlying values for those columns are text/string, so you cannot apply numbers formatting to the cells (in those columns) unless you convert the values to numeric data first. I think you may try to convert the string values to appropriate data type (e.g Numeric) while you are inserting the value into the cells via Aspose.Cells APIs from your data source/variables. You should pick appropriate Cell.PutValue() overloaded method for your requirements, you need to specify the second Boolean parameter to true. So, you may try to change the lines of code (from the code segment) to:
e.g
Sample code:

```
Cell CWeekCell = customerWorksheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, CWEEK_COL];
        **CWeekCell.PutValue(frbdbc.CWeek, true);**
        var cwStyle = CWeekCell.GetStyle();
        cwStyle.Font.Name = fontForSheets;
        cwStyle.IsTextWrapped = false;
        cwStyle.Custom = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.NUMBER_FORMAT_ZERO;
        CWeekCell.SetStyle(cwStyle, flag);

        Cell PAItemCell = customerWorksheet.Cells[rowToPopulate, PAITEMCODE_COL];
        **PAItemCell.PutValue(frbdbc.PAItemCode, true);**
        var paiStyle = PAItemCell.GetStyle();
        paiStyle.Font.Name = fontForSheets;
        paiStyle.IsTextWrapped = false;
        //paiStyle.Custom = RoboReporterConstsAndUtils.NUMBER_FORMAT_ZERO;
        PAItemCell.SetStyle(paiStyle); //, flag);
```

.............

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: So all that's needed is the "true" arg for PutValue()? One (CWeekCell) has a Custom value supplied, the second has it commented out. Which should it be - assigned a value, or ignored?

Comment: Assignment to Custom not needed (empirically established).

Comment: Yes, you got it right. You may always use that overload of PutValue method while specifying the second parameter to "true" when you feel that the numeric data is in string format (in your source objects/variables).

Answer (score 1):

I just recorded a macro for a quick and dirty solution:

```
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("G1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

I know that performing a "Text to columns" operation on these "text" cells will strip the unseen apostrophe and thus convert the cells into a number (extremely quickly). Give this a shot and please let me know how it pans out.

e-P.S. this above macro was recorded by Microsoft using the macro recorder.

Comment: Thanks, but I would need a way to do this in code, or a way to programmatically embed a macro in an .xlsx file. I don't know if it's even possible to do the latter.

Comment: Ahh yes, the .xlsx dilemma. This caused a catastrophe at my last job. The only work around I found was to have an external controller (this can be an .xlsm file with buttons if you like, for simplicity) that will make the alterations to the .xlsx file.

Comment: Yeah, they definitely won't want to do something like that. Thanks, though.